# Error linking shared library

Tags: 14.04, python, compiling, root

I am trying to install root software which is giving the following error when I type `make -j4` in terminal :

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libPyROOT.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(myreadline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libPyROOT.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [bindings/pyroot/CMakeFiles/PyROOT.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am unable to make any sense of it though I have been trying for a long time. Can someone please help me? I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installed with Python 2.7.8.

Thanks.